# Define operator in SWI Prolog

Tags: prolog, operators

I am trying to define an operator in SWI Prolog.

```
:- op(700, xfx, and).
```

when I load file with above line, it returns `true`, but when I try `p and q`, I get back:

```
ERROR: Undefined procedure: (and)/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

I looked through documentation, but it is very minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining the atom `and` as an infix **operator** makes `a and b` a syntactically valid term **but** doesn't define an `and/2` **predicate**, hence the error you got.

Your question hints that you are trying to write some code for propositional logic. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, I am going through set of exercises from this link: http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse42

Comment: If we do a search for "prolog proposition logic" here in SO, you will get some related questions that may help.